# Must remove then connect battery to charge

Tags: 20.04, power-management, battery

I recently purchased BT04 BT04XL Battery Replacement for an HP EliteBook Folio 9470M running 20.04 LTS. The battery is recognized and will discharge power when unplugged, but later, in order to recharge (when the laptop is plugged back in) the battery must first be removed (disconnected) from the laptop and then reinstalled. Once reconnected, the battery will charge normally.

Any ideas?

Obligatory battery info...

```
upower -i `upower -e | grep 'BAT'`
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Hewlett-Packard
  model:                Primary
  serial:               03110 2021/03/03
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri 02 Jul 2021 08:22:23 AM EDT (44 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              56.1312 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         59.5008 Wh
    energy-full-design:  59.5008 Wh
    energy-rate:         1.4688 W
    voltage:             17.294 V
    percentage:          94%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'

acpi -V
Battery 0: Unknown, 94%
Battery 0: design capacity 4132 mAh, last full capacity 4132 mAh = 100%
Adapter 0: on-line
Thermal 0: ok, 24.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 128.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 1 switches to mode passive at temperature 55.0 degrees C
Thermal 1: ok, 0.0 degrees C
Thermal 1: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 128.0 degrees C
Thermal 1: trip point 1 switches to mode passive at temperature 108.0 degrees C
Thermal 2: ok, 39.0 degrees C
Thermal 2: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 128.0 degrees C
Thermal 3: ok, 127.0 degrees C
Thermal 3: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 128.0 degrees C
Thermal 4: ok, 52.0 degrees C
Thermal 4: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 128.0 degrees C
Thermal 4: trip point 1 switches to mode hot at temperature 104.0 degrees C
Thermal 5: ok, 40.0 degrees C
Thermal 5: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 128.0 degrees C
Cooling 0: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 1: x86_pkg_temp no state information available
Cooling 2: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 3: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 4: intel_powerclamp no state information available
Cooling 5: Processor 0 of 10
```

Comment: Before obtaining a new battery, did you make any changes to the charging threshold values in Ubuntu to extend the previous battery?

Comment: I doubt this is something related to Ubuntu. If the battery needs to be removed I would believe it is a hardware problem. Maybe the connection point is not clean or skewed?

Comment: @matigo, thanks for taking the time to look at this. No, I did not change any power settings.

Comment: @Rinzwind. Thanks so you too. I will take a look and try cleaning the connection points.